# Oracle Data Gaps

Tags: sql, oracle

im looking for a query to fill this condition:

That currently gives us the number of BACs at the entity (which is something we need). The database assigns the BAC IDs consecutively within each accounting entity. So we need to add one more field to the query showing the current highest BAC ID at the entity. And once we have that, just filter the results down to anyplace the number of records doesn't equal the highest ID.

My current query:

```
 select accounting_entity_id, count(bac_id)
 from dc.pl_bac_information
 group by accounting_entity_id
 having count(bac_id) > 1;
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because you specify Oracle in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID
  FROM DC.PL_BAC_INFORMATION
HAVING COUNT(BAC_ID) > 1 AND COUNT(BAC_ID) != MAX(BAC_ID)
 GROUP BY ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use analytic functions for this:

```
select bi.*
from (select bi.*, max(bac_id) over (partition by accounting_entity_id) as max_bac_id
      from dc.pl_bac_information bi
     ) bi
where bac_id = max_bac_id;
```

This assumes you are using Oracle.

Comment: i also need to add one more field to the query showing the current highest BAC ID at the entity. And once we have that, just filter the results down to anyplace the number of records doesn't equal the highest ID.

Comment: SELECT ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID, COUNT(BAC_ID)
  FROM DC.PL_BAC_INFORMATION
WHERE ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID = 359
GROUP BY ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID;


SELECT ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID, MAX(BAC_ID)
  FROM DC.PL_BAC_INFORMATION
WHERE ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID = 359
GROUP BY ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID;

What we need to do is write a query that combines the top two queries and compares them.  We need to know where the count <> the highest id value.

Comment: If you want where things don't equal the highest id, then use `where bac_id < max_bac_id`.

Comment: select A.ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID, MAX(A.BAC_ID) BACID
  FROM DC.PL_BAC_INFORMATION A
 WHERE 'BACID' <>
       (SELECT COUNT(BAC_ID) currentvalue from DC.PL_BAC_INFORMATION)
 group by ACCOUNTING_ENTITY_ID;